# move_uploaded_file function does not work

Tags: php, html

Why move_uploaded_file function does not work I have created a form in which I will upload some audio to the server folder but "move_uploaded_file" does not move the file. I don't know where I am wrong can please anyone help me.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="uploading.php" method="post">
<input type="file" name= "audioFile"/><br>
<input type="Submit" value="Upload" name="Save_audio"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My HTML Code

uploading.php code

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['Save_audio']) && $_POST['Save_audio']=="Upload")
    {
        $dir='Uploads/';
        $audio_path=$dir.basename($_FILES['audioFile']['name']);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audioFile']['tmp_name'], $audio_path))
        {
            echo 'Uploaded';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Please make another question and don't paste over your original question. This is not how SO works.

Answer (score 2):

Don't assume a PHP function "doesn't work".  Debug.  In this case your browser isn't sending the file to the server at all.

Your form element is missing the encoding:

```
<form action="uploading.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Without the `enctype` the default encoding is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which can't hold files.

Comment: @RohitChauhan: Debug.  In your browser's debugging tools, is the file sent to the server?  In the server-side code, what is in `$_FILES`?  What is in `$_POST`?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are missed `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in **form**

```
<form action="uploading.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```